# What happens when two persons post the answer at the same time?

Tags: support

Lets say I got a question open in my browser and started preparing answer for it. When I came back in the browser and posted my answer, I found the same answer was already given by someone else. Since I didn't refresh the page I didn't get that someone has posted the answer. So what can I do? Should I keep the answer though its almost similar? Or I should delete my answer?

Comment: Whatever you prefer really. Delete it, improve it, mark it as Community Wiki. Just be careful, not to delete it at the same time as the other person, if you decide that ;)

Comment: A recent case where 2 answers of the 3 (from usr and Daniel) were essentially the same. They left them and both got to +11 (so far): [Field order in a composite index order with high selectivity and low selectivity fields](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129604/field-order-in-a-composite-index-order-with-high-selectivity-and-low-selectivity)

Comment: Well here is one example.[How to reformat Oracle SQL quadratic-equation solver script?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130322/how-to-reformat-oracle-sql-quadratic-equation-solver-script). Codes can be identical, can have same approach to write code. There will not be any down votes and comments regarding the same answer from moderators' site?

Comment: Maybe, we can't tell what will happen from a moderator's point of view. His answer was there first, some people might think his deserves the vote, and they can vote however they feel. We can't control or even know how individual users vote, never mind why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't tell you what you should do. We have no way to know how users will react to duplicate answers.

This question has been addressed on the main meta (the core concepts here are really not anything specific about this site):

- [Should I still post an answer if I see several answers have already been posted while writing an answer or making a fiddle?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136640/should-i-still-post-an-answer-if-i-see-several-answers-have-already-been-posted)
- [Do you delete your own answer when it's a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate)